# If we forget which slit the photon goes through, does it interfere again?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Okay, this highly hypothetical, since forgetting is basically impossible. I am just testing my understanding of quantum mechanics, this exact experiment is basically impossible (although there may be similar ones in quantum computing that are).

So, let's say you have (I won't be doing normalization):

$$|\text{slit 1}\rangle+|\text{slit2}\rangle$$

If we do not observe which slit it goes through, we get (say):

$$i|\text{left}\rangle + |\text{middle}\rangle-|\text{middle}\rangle-i|\text{right}\rangle=i|\text{left}\rangle -i|\text{right}\rangle$$

So we have a half probability of the particle being in the left detector, and a half probability of it being in the right. Now let's add an observer.

$$|\text{slit 1, slit 1 observed}\rangle+|\text{slit2, slit 2 observed}\rangle$$

Now this transforms into:

$$i|\text{left, slit 1 observed}\rangle + |\text{middle, slit 1 observed}\rangle-|\text{middle, slit 2 observed}\rangle-i|\text{right, slit 2 observed}\rangle$$

So now the probability of the middle detector is a half, and the left and right are a fourth each.

This is basic double slit experiment stuff.

---

Let's go back to

$$|\text{slit 1, slit 1 observed}\rangle+|\text{slit2, slit 2 observed}\rangle$$

Now let's say we un-observe what slit it goes through. We erase the computer's, burn the security cam footage, brainwash the scientists, and, as the coup de grâce, call up [Maxwell's demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon) and have him put every single particle back where it was. Now we have

$$|\text{slit 1, slit unobserved}\rangle+|\text{slit2, slit unobserved}\rangle$$

Which transforms into

$$i|\text{left, slit unobserved}\rangle + |\text{middle, slit unobserved}\rangle-|\text{middle, slit unobserved}\rangle-i|\text{right, slit unobserved}\rangle=i|\text{left, slit unobserved}\rangle -i|\text{right, slit unobserved}\rangle$$

Just like we never observed it in the first place.

Is this correct? Also, as follow up:

What if we have Maxwell's demon trick everyone/everything into thinking it goes through the left slit anytime it goes through the right slit, but **not** vice versa. Would it be like it was unobserved?

Comment: Are you asking about a [quantum eraser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_eraser_experiment)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I guess so. That answers my question then.

Comment: I'm very confused why there are 4 votes to close a quantum eraser question as non-mainstream.